# IBOutlet variables return nil when I try to access them. Error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, mkmapview, mapbox

I have a `UIViewController` that implements `MGLMapViewDelegate`. I'm trying to place a nav bar at the top, with two buttons.

I couldn't get my buttons or nav bar visible so I tried using the function `view.bringSubviewToFront()` within my `viewDidLoadFunction()` as suggested on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520776/how-to-display-something-over-the-google-map)

When I did this, I received the error

> Error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I don't understand how the `IBOutlet` variables can ever be nil, I thought they were assigned to the storyboard buttons

---

**My ViewController Class(At least the parts that I think are important)**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {

...

var mapView: MGLMapView?
@IBOutlet var navBar: UINavigationBar!
@IBOutlet var signOutButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var newPostButton: UIButton!

...

override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

    self.mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: MGLStyle.lightStyleURL)

    ...

        view.addSubview(self.mapView!)

        view.addSubview(navBar)
        view.addSubview(signOutButton)
        view.addSubview(newPostButton)
        //Make the navBar and Buttons visible
        view.bringSubviewToFront(self.navBar)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(self.signOutButton)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(self.newPostButton)

        ...
}

...

@objc func handleLogout() {
     let loginController = SignInViewController()

     do {
          try Auth.auth().signOut()
      } catch let logoutError {
          print(logoutError)
      }

      present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

---

**Some screenshots of my storyboard I thought might be important**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[I've tried placing this in my view controller right after super.viewDidLoad()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948302/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value)

```
self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainViewController") as! ViewController
```

I've tried bringing the view to the front of the mapview instead of the main view

```
self.mapView.bringViewToFront(navBar)
```

[I've tried placing the code inside functions like awakeFromNib and viewDidLayoutSubviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397279/nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-iboutlet-value)

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        //Make the navBar and Buttons visible
        self.mapView!.bringSubviewToFront(self.navBar)
        self.mapView!.bringSubviewToFront(self.signOutButton)
        self.mapView!.bringSubviewToFront(self.newPostButton)

    }
```

Comment: Did you check if your mapView is nil?

Comment: why view.addSubview(signOutButton) if they already are in the storyboard?

Comment: @Teetz I didn't, but it happens for just `view.addSubview` which wouldn't be mapView. I'll try though

Comment: @Alastar That's a debugging attempt at making sure the buttons are in the view, it wasn't present on my first attempt. I could take it out if you think that would make it more clear or better?

Comment: `var mapView: MGLMapView?` has to be the  MapView  in the ViewController Scene?

Comment: @Alastar I'm using MapBox, it's very similar to mapkit but there's a few other things that belong to it. I can usually use instructions that are meant for mapkit, and they work with mapbox except for changing the class names from something like MKMapView to MGLMapView.

Comment: @Jacob - put a breakpoint at `super.viewDidLoad()` and step through... Make sure you know exactly which line is throwing the "Unexpectedly found nil" error.

Comment: check whether mapview is nil after allocation.

Comment: @DonMag It shows the "Thread 1" error right beside view.addSubview(navBar), if I remove navBar it shows it beside `view.addSubview(signOutButton)`, I haven't gone into these functions because I know it will be a bunch of stuff I don't understand and probably won't help me much. I could try though if there's something specific you think I should look for inside them?

Comment: @AbhijithPurushothaman Both view and mapview are non-nil optionals. The other 3 vars print nil

Comment: @Jacob - do you have more than one Storyboard in your project? If so, is it possible you have your Main Interface set to a different Storyboard, with a different View Controller?

Comment: @DonMag I have launchScreen.storyboard, which I think is there when I create the project. I haven't used it or touch it really. I do have 2 scenes in my storyboard though. I have a login page, which is the first page, and the next page(the mapview) is opened up by calling `let mainController = ViewController()` and then `self.present(mainController, animated:true, completion:nil)`

Comment: Are you accessing these IBOutlets values after instantiation but before presenting/Pushing ? Can you add the code how you present/alocate this view controller ?

Comment: This is wrong --> let mainController = ViewController()
Use instantiateViewController, then push/present

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments, I understood that you are instantiating the controller wrongly.

```
let mainController = ViewController(). // Wrong
```

This will just instantiate the ViewController but not any objects from the story board.

**Use below code to instantiate viewcontroller from storyboard.**

```
    if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainViewController") as? ViewController {
        //Set any data if required, then present
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

If you use **multiple storyBoards,**

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainViewController") as? ViewController {
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

Comment: I tried this and nothing happened, so I tried `dump(self.storyboard)` and got nil. I feel like it's worth mentioning that the class that called self.storyboard isn't from the storyboard. It's a view controller I wrote in code. Is the easiest way to create a view controller pane in my storyboard for this class?

Comment: My login storyboard scene goes to the mainView, but it also goes to some other view controllers that link to the main view, so sorry if that confused you

Comment: So I used `if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainViewController") as? ViewController {` and it worked. Your answer is the way to do it though if your following good practice though. Maybe add a note about how if the view is on a different storyboard you can call `UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController`? It's up to you, i'm sure someone will be glad you did though.

Comment: Yeah I did that..!